# Effect of Singleton classes in Webservices

Tags: java, web-services, singleton

I am implementing a webapplication and providing few rest APIs.

Following is the structure of my webapplication.

***Service Layer***
**Service class** contains different APIs.

It invokes **DAO** which is a **singleton class**(I would rather say that it is an **Enum** and only instance has been defined for **Enum**) and it does not have any state. I mean there are no instance variable in DAO layer classes.

***DAO Layer***
DAO class fetches **DB connection** (DB connection is provided through **Enum** class, and I created the connection at the time of **instantiating the Enum**), and it execute respective query on the DB.

So Application architecture is like this.

```
ServiceClass {
    Dao.operation()
}

DaoEnum {

    instance;

    operation() {
        DBConnectionEnum.instance.connection.preparedStmt.respective operation
    }
}

DBConnectionEnum {
    DBConnectionEnum() {
        grabDBConnection()
    }
}
```

I understand I have to use connectionpool to grab db connection, but I am unable to understand the impacts caused by Dao layer, which is singleton.

Could you suggest me whether it is a correct design, or will it exhaust the application? What improvements can be made to make application more robust, fast and performant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was discussing the issue with my colleague and as per the discussion I felt my singleton DAO layer must not cause any issues for me.

As DAO layer is working as a mediator between DB and Service class, and DAO layer do not maintain any state. So when 2 similar requests are invoked simultaneously, then both requests will be served in 2 different threads and each thread will maintain its own Stack. When both the requests call DAO layer, these requests will simply invoke DAO layer's method which will be associated with the respective thread's stack.

So If I create Singleton DAO layer in my application to serve multiple web requests, it will not exhaust throughput and clients must be served without any issue.

Hope I am making little sense. :)

Answer (score 0):

the Singleton design pattern is a good pattern on its own, otherwise it would not have lasted this long. There are some [drawbacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#Drawbacks), like introducing global state into your application. But I don't think those downsides are enough to discount it. However there are better ways of doing what you're trying to do. [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_Injection) is one way of abstracting invocation from implementation. You can even use a Singleton in your DI Implementation, as long as it's transparent from the invocation. I would highly recommend that you do some research on DI.

Comment: My web application is quite simple, I do not want to clutter with unwanted frameworks. Though your suggestion is worthy if I were implementing huge application. Could you elaborate the drawbacks in terms of my design?

Comment: Well, for a simple program, that would suffice. Just remember that with a singleton only one request at a time can be processed. If you have multiple request coming in, their threads will block until the Singleton is available. if your DAO queries take too long, that might become an issue.